# PySide6 app packaged with PyInstaller not starting with no errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside6

I am trying to create a standalone PySide6 application executable. My setup is:

- Python venv
- Python 3.9
- PySide 6.1.0
- Pyinstaller 4.3
- 64-bit Windows 10

It is a simple script like this :

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication)
import sys

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("hellooo")

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The app runs fine as a script. But when I convert it to an exe using Pyinstaller like so:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --debug=all --windowed --console hello.py
```

the app does not start and exits immediately and no meaningful error shows up. Console output is like this:

```
[12384] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[12384] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[12384] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[12384] LOADER: extracted struct
[12384] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[12384] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[12384] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[12384] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[12384] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[12384] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[12384] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[12384] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[12384] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[12384] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[12384] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[12384] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_certifi.py
[12384] LOADER: Running main_window.py
[408] LOADER: Back to parent (RC: -1073741819)
[408] LOADER: Doing cleanup
```

My actual application is more complex than this. I was just using the above example to see if it could work as an exe but both have the same issue.

NOTE: I have looked at all the related issues on this site and elsewhere but none helped.

NOTE: the problem mentioned in the first comment below about qt platform not found is not the issue I have. I have resolved that particular error as I mention in my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/deployment.html#deployment-guides) to docs where you can find a table which summarize the platform support for different packaging tools.

[Table: support for packaging tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFiWQ.png)

According to that table, at the present moment Qt6 only has partial support for PyInstaller.

But Qt official website has a blog [post](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-6.1), where they wrote about [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/):

> Compiling Python applications is complicated work, and many Qt for Python users are always looking for ways to deploy standalone binaries from their Python applications. This is why we created all the tools tutorials in our documentation.
>
> So far, all the solutions are based on the idea of packaging the Python code, and distributing it, but none of them was focused on compiling the code, here is where Nuitka ticks all the boxes.
>
> We love Nuitka, and we are certain you will love it too!
>
> If this name is new to you, in a nutshell we can tell you that it’s a Python compiler written in Python, you can read more in their website.
>
> We are thankful for all the time Kay Hayen took to make Nuitka compatible with PySide 6.1, and we are looking forward to hearing from your own experiences what we could improve from this joint effort.

I think you can try it instead of PyInstaller.

Comment: I was looking for a fix for PyInstaller with PySide6 but switching to Nuikta just work nearly out of the box.

I've used this command line: `python -m nuitka --standalone --enable-plugin=pyside6 main.py`